# How to covert a tensor with an unknown dimension to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensor

I have a tensor with the dimensions `<tf.Tensor 'conv2d_1/Relu:0' shape=(?, 32, 24, 24) dtype=float32>`. The first dimension is not known. How do I convert this to a numpy array?

I have used the following code

```
sess = tf.Session()
with sess.as_default():
        y = tf.shape(x)
        nx = y.eval()
        print(nx)
```

Here, x is the input tensor.

Comment: the dimension `?` will take the size of your batch: so if you train the network with batch_size = 4 then `? = 4`

Comment: I am using a grayscale image. The image size is 24x24 after a single convolution operation. Then 32 is the batch size, right?
I'm quite unexperienced in this area.

Comment: your input will be: `(batch_size, width, height, channels)` with 1 channel as greyscale. batch_size can be changed, did you chose `32`? 24x24 will depend on your input shape, kernel size, stride and padding.

Comment: @RanganDas  Did you find the answer for your question?